# How to write an executable such that it provides a modding friendly api?

Tags: api, rust

I'm currently researching how to provide an api of sorts for users who write mods for my program. My program is written in Rust.

Currently, when I compile my program as a library, I'm able to provide functions which aren't mangled and which have C bindings. When I compile my program as a executable, I lose the ability to call those functions.

What I'd like to do is make it so someone can write a mod for my program (for example, in C or Rust), and then when my program detects the mod (say inside the mods folder), the mod would load and would be able to interface with my program and call my functions which I make available to the modders.

How would I provide a modding friendly api for my program?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a number of different ways, each differing in its tradeoffs. I would recommend you read a fantastic series of blog posts [A Plugin System in Rust](https://nullderef.com/series/rust-plugins/). The first post explains many possible approaches and in the following their implementation is shown and discussed. It is very in-depth and goes event into such subject as abi safety.